# Provide value to property on construction time, without doing it inline

Tags: c#

I would like to do a refactoring that will let me define the collection of fields somewhere else than inline at the initialization of `Fields`.

I'm confused by the error message as I'm still providing the value when it's constructed, I'm not modifying `A` after it's constructed (as far as I know).

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and tell me how to provide a list of `Field`s that are not defined inline?

---

Definition of A:

```cs
public record A
{
    public A(String text)
    {
        this.Fields = new List<Field>();
    }

    public List<Field> Fields { get; }
}
```

Example before:

```cs
public static class MyClass
{
    public static A Build()
    {
        return new A("some date")
        {
            Fields =
            {
                Field1,
                Field2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example after:

```cs
public static class MyClassyClass
{
    public static List<Field> GetMeTheFields()
    {
        return new List<Field>
        {
            Field1,
            Field2
        };
    }

    public static A Build()
    {
        return new A("some date")
        {
            Fields = GetMeTheFields()
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error message:

> A property without setter or inaccessible setter cannot be assigned to

Comment: To explain why you're getting the error in the 2nd case and not the 1st: The 1st case gets converted into a pair of `A.Fields.Add(Field1);` calls (i.e. NOT assigning the Fields property, just invoking the Add method on it), meanwhile the 2nd case gets converted into a `A.Fields = GetMeTheFields();` call (trying to assign to the property, thus triggering the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you cannot modify class `A` to add an `init` setter to `Fields` property, here's how you can provide a list of `Field`s to `Fields` a different way, based on your "example after":

```
public static class MyClassyClass
{
    public static List<Field> GetMeTheFields()
    {
        return new List<Field>
        {
            Field1,
            Field2
        };
    }

    public static A Build()
    {
        var a = new A("some date");

        a.Fields.AddRange(GetMeTheFields());

        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an `init` clause to the `Fields` property definition and you are good to go.

```
public List<Field> Fields { get; init; }
```

This will allow you to modify the `Fields` property inside the constructors or via an object initializer.

Your code has failed because the property without `set` or `init` can't be initialized inside the object initializer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
There's one thing I forgot to mention: `A` is generate by another part of the organization. 
While I can probably make them change this, it will take some time (large company).
Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: @LittleHelper You can simply add them with the `AddRange` command: `a.AddRange(GetMeTheFields());`